# Insert Where Value is not null

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have the following code on my Excel VBA:

```
Sub Button3_Click()
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    conn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=myServer;Database=myDatabase;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

    iRowNo = 6

    Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
        dtDateTime = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
        sTag = .Cells(iRowNo, 10)
        conn.Execute "insert into RawData(oDateTime,oTag) values ('" & dtDateTime & "', '" & sTag & "')"

        iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing..."
    Loop
    MsgBox "Upload success!", vbInformation, "AOA"

    Sheet1.Range("A6", "L100000").ClearContents
    Sheet1.Cells(6, 1).Select

    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End With
End Sub
```

If you check the code above, there're two value to be add to the table. Is it possible to skip the record when `sTag` cell is null?
If `sTag` cell is null, then insert the next record. Something like that.

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: why not just write an If Not IsEmpty(sTag) Then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do inserts conditionally, i.e. wrap insert command execution in `If` statement, where you check `sTag` for emptiness.

```
If sTag <> "" Then
    conn.Execute "insert into RawData(oDateTime,oTag) values ('" & dtDateTime & "', '" & sTag & "')"
End If
```

Comment: `If sTag <> "" Or IsEmpty(sTag) = False`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        conn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=myServer;Database=myDatabase;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

        iRowNo = 6

        Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
            dtDateTime = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
            sTag = .Cells(iRowNo, 10)
            If sTag <> "" Then
                conn.Execute "insert into RawData(oDateTime,oTag) values ('" & dtDateTime & "', '" & sTag &     "')"
            End If

            iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
            Application.StatusBar = "Processing..."
        Loop
        MsgBox "Upload success!", vbInformation, "AOA"

        Sheet1.Range("A6", "L100000").ClearContents
        Sheet1.Cells(6, 1).Select

        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing
    End With
End Sub
```